# Ordenar una Consulta de varias rows en una row con Linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

Estoy tratando de ordenar una consulta con **`Linq`** donde tengo resultado de un **`Query`** en **`SQL server`** con varias **rows** , quisiera agruparlo por cliente donde me muestre la información en una sola columna por año.

La consulta a manejar es el siguiente:

```
año    mes  Oficina Cliente  Moneda total
--------------------------------------------
2017    3   O1        Cliente1  USD    3250
2017    5   O1        Cliente1  USD    55000
2018    3   O1        Cliente1  USD    7900
2018    4   O1        Cliente1  USD    7900
2018    7   O1        Cliente1  USD    7900
2017    3   O2        Cliente2  EUR    145,7
2017    7   O2        Cliente2  EUR    6000
2017    2   O2        Cliente3  USD    23250
2017    3   O2        Cliente3  USD    2331,64
2017    4   O2        Cliente3  USD    1504,32
2017    5   O2        Cliente3  USD    1504,32
```

se quiere presentar de la siguiente forma:

```
oficina  cliente  enero   febrero marzo   abril  ....   diciembre total
======== ======== ======= ======= ======= ===== ======= ========= =====
```

quisiera saber si hay una forma mediante **`Linq`** obtener el resultado esperado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He resuelto a mi pregunta gracias a la respuesta [Sort a Query of multi-rows in a row with Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57902559/11606342)

```
Dim amountPerGroup = From row In table.AsEnumerable
                   Group row By myGroup = New With {
                                                Key .ano = row.Field(Of Integer)("año"),
                                                Key .Oficina = row.Field(Of String)("Oficina"),
                                                Key .Cliente = row.Field(Of String)("Cliente"),
                                                Key .Moneda = row.Field(Of String)("Moneda")
                                           } Into Group
                   Select New With {
                                   myGroup.ano, myGroup.Oficina, myGroup.Cliente, myGroup.Moneda,
                                  .SumJan = Group.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToDouble(IIf(x.Field(Of Integer)("mes") = 1, x.Field(Of Double)("total"), 0))),
                                  .SumFeb = Group.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToDouble(IIf(x.Field(Of Integer)("mes") = 2, x.Field(Of Double)("total"), 0))),
                                  .SumMar = Group.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToDouble(IIf(x.Field(Of Integer)("mes") = 3, x.Field(Of Double)("total"), 0))),
                                  .SumApr = Group.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToDouble(IIf(x.Field(Of Integer)("mes") = 4, x.Field(Of Double)("total"), 0))),
                                  .SumMay = Group.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToDouble(IIf(x.Field(Of Integer)("mes") = 5, x.Field(Of Double)("total"), 0))),
                                  .SumJun = Group.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToDouble(IIf(x.Field(Of Integer)("mes") = 6, x.Field(Of Double)("total"), 0))),
                                  .SumJul = Group.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToDouble(IIf(x.Field(Of Integer)("mes") = 7, x.Field(Of Double)("total"), 0))),
                                  .SumAug = Group.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToDouble(IIf(x.Field(Of Integer)("mes") = 8, x.Field(Of Double)("total"), 0))),
                                  .SumSep = Group.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToDouble(IIf(x.Field(Of Integer)("mes") = 9, x.Field(Of Double)("total"), 0))),
                                  .SumOct = Group.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToDouble(IIf(x.Field(Of Integer)("mes") = 10, x.Field(Of Double)("total"), 0))),
                                  .SumNov = Group.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToDouble(IIf(x.Field(Of Integer)("mes") = 11, x.Field(Of Double)("total"), 0))),
                                  .SumDec = Group.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToDouble(IIf(x.Field(Of Integer)("mes") = 12, x.Field(Of Double)("total"), 0)))}
```